# Changing element positions on page load jQuery

Tags: jquery, html, responsive-design

So here is my code that I had gotten from a previous answer to someoneelses question.

```
$(document).load($(window).bind("resize", listenWidth));

            function listenWidth( e ) {
                if($(window).width()<500)
                {
                    $("#sidebar").remove().insertBefore($(".page"));
                } else if ($(window).width()>500) {
                    $("#sidebar").remove().insertBefore($(".introTop"));
                }
            }
```

So that works all good and well changing the position on resize but when it is loaded and the screen is already less than 500px it doesn't do anything until I resize the page.

Can this be fixed so it will initialize on the load and place my element accordingly as well as listening for the resize?

Thanks in advance,

Peter.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should use bind `resize` event and [`trigger()`](http://api.jquery.com/trigger/) it on page load

```
$(window).load(function() {
    $(window).on("resize", function(e) { //Bind resize
        if ($(window).width() < 500) {
            $("#sidebar").remove().insertBefore($(".page"));
        } else if ($(window).width() > 500) {
            $("#sidebar").remove().insertBefore($(".introTop"));
        }
    }).trigger("resize"); //Trigger on page load
});
```

Comment: Neat. Could also be split to two bindings for readability but does the trick either way.

Comment: Link: [Slightly more compact version of the same thing](http://jsfiddle.net/lollero/7cka8jsz/)

Answer (score 0):

Just activate the function on document ready....

```
$(function() {
  $(document).load($(window).bind("resize", listenWidth));
  listenWidth();
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Yes Of course

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    listenWidth(e);
});
```

This shall work on document ready

Answer (score 0):

You don't need to wrap that in DOM ready in the first place. And then you can just trigger it:

```
$(window).bind("resize", listenWidth).trigger('resize');
```

Answer (score 0):

Or you may write your code on window load

```
$(window).on('resize', function(e){
    listenWidth(e);
});
$(window).load(function(e){
    $(window).trigger('resize');
});
```